# model comparison interpretation when chi square equals 0

Tags: r, lme4, anova, chi-squared, model-comparison

I'm comparing two multilevel models in R using the anova() function. One model contains a control variable and another with an experimental variable. When I compare the two, I get a weird result where the chisquare is 0 and the p value is 1. I would interpret this as the models are not significantly different, but this doesn't make sense with the data and other analyses that I've done with this experimental variable. Can someone help me understand this output?

To explain the variables, block_order (control) is the counterbalancing of the questions. It's a factor with 5 levels.
team_num is a level 2 random effect; it's the participant's team that they belong to.
cent_team_wm_agg is the team's desire to maintain a healthy weight. It is a continuous variable.
exer_vig is the continuous dependent variable, and it is how often people exercise.

Here's the model comparison output that has me confused:

```
anova(m2_ev_full_team, m1_ev_control_block_team) 

refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
Data: clean_data_0_nona
Models:
m2_ev_full_team: exer_vig ~ 1 + cent_team_wm_agg + (1 | team_num)
m1_ev_control_block_team: exer_vig ~ 1 + block_order + (1 | team_num)
                         Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
m2_ev_full_team           4 523.75 536.27 -257.88   515.75                        
m1_ev_control_block_team  8 533.96 559.00 -258.98   517.96     0      4          1
```

In case this helps, here are the models themselves. This is the one with the experimental variable:

```
summary(m2_ev_full_team <- lmer(exer_vig ~ 1 + cent_team_wm_agg + (1 |team_num), data = clean_data_0_nona))
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: exer_vig ~ 1 + cent_team_wm_agg + (1 | team_num)
   Data: clean_data_0_nona

REML criterion at convergence: 519.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7585 -0.5819 -0.2432  0.5531  2.5569 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 team_num (Intercept) 0.1004   0.3168  
 Residual             1.1628   1.0783  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  team_num, 58

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       2.65955    0.09478 42.39962  28.061   <2e-16 ***
cent_team_wm_agg  0.73291    0.23572 64.27148   3.109   0.0028 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
cnt_tm_wm_g -0.004
```

And the one with the control:

```
summary(m1_ev_control_block_team <- lmer(exer_vig ~ 1 + block_order + (1  |team_num), data = clean_data_0_nona))
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: exer_vig ~ 1 + block_order + (1 | team_num)
   Data: clean_data_0_nona

REML criterion at convergence: 525.1

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6796 -0.6597 -0.1625  0.5291  2.0941 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 team_num (Intercept) 0.2499   0.4999  
 Residual             1.1003   1.0490  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  team_num, 58

Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       3.0874     0.2513 155.4960  12.284   <2e-16 ***
block_orderBlock2|Block4|Block3  -0.2568     0.3057 154.8652  -0.840   0.4020    
block_orderBlock3|Block2|Block4  -0.3036     0.3438 160.8279  -0.883   0.3785    
block_orderBlock3|Block4|Block2  -0.6204     0.3225 161.5186  -1.924   0.0561 .  
block_orderBlock4|Block2|Block3  -0.4215     0.3081 151.2908  -1.368   0.1733    
block_orderBlock4|Block3|Block2  -0.7306     0.3178 156.5548  -2.299   0.0228 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) b_B2|B b_B3|B2 b_B3|B4 b_B4|B2
bl_B2|B4|B3 -0.757                               
bl_B3|B2|B4 -0.687  0.557                        
bl_B3|B4|B2 -0.733  0.585  0.543                 
bl_B4|B2|B3 -0.741  0.601  0.545   0.577         
bl_B4|B3|B2 -0.734  0.586  0.535   0.561   0.575
```

EDIT: If I had to guess, I assume it's because the control model has more degrees of freedom than the experimental, but that's all I can think of. I've tried running anova with the order of the models flipped, but it doesn't change anything. If that's the case, I don't know why the number of dfs would make a difference in being able to compare which one is better.

Thank you!

Comment: You are using the anova in a very unconventional way. Usually we test this with a full model against a reduced model, to see whether adding another term, explains more variance. Therefore, if your df of the model increases, the log likelihood should increase too

Comment: From what I can see, your experimental variable has some association with your response, which is good. Your control variables on the other hand, not much effect. So build the full model with lmer(exer_vig ~ 1 + block_order+ cent_team_wm_agg + (1 |team_num) ...  and test it against the reduced model,lmer(1 + block_order + (1|team_num))

Comment: This seems like an `AIC` situation, rather than anova, if you want to see which of your two models is better.